# Getting error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to add a column to a view with the following code:

```
SELECT ';' + CONTEXT as DriverNotes,

(STUFF((SELECT CustomerID FROM Notes E2 WHERE E2.CustomerID IN (Notes.CustomerID)
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]','nvarchar(5)'),1,0,'')) as CustomerID FROM NOTES
```

On it's own it works just fine. When I run it within a View however, I get the following error:

"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

I realize that the code here is trying to call two columns and that is what is giving me the error, but I only want one, and that would be CONTEXT. I need this to correlate with Notes.CustomerID but without the column appearing in the query.

I am still quite new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you "run it in a view"? What is the definition of your View?

Comment: Sorry I am probably using the wrong terminology, but I have dropped and created a view with the intention of adding the code I posted above. When I go to execute the query, I get the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Check this query. I think this is what you want :

```
SELECT Notes.CustomerId, 
    STUFF(
            (SELECT ';' + CONTEXT FROM Notes E2 
                WHERE E2.CustomerId = Notes.CustomerId
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
            ) DriverNotes
FROM Notes /*Probably it should be Customer table */
GROUP BY Notes.CustomerId
```

Comment: This works similar to the code I posted. It does not work when creating a View though. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I did, I also added the View I am trying to edit. The expected output would be to just add a single column "Context" to [dbo].[VCustomerJoinLocations].